# Save(cache) a cardview and it's detail view locally

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to implement a “save“ option on cardview items. I want to know how can I cache/save a cardview so I still can interact with it even if it has been remove from database hence updated in the UI tab but still accessible locally in the SAVED tab.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's gone from the DB, then it's gone gone. You'd have to spin up a local Room instance or something which won't work anyway when the user tries to use your app on another device. A much simpler solution would be to simply [enable offline persistance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).

Does that answer your question? I wasn't quite sure what you meant by available "locally." ‍♂️

Comment: Thanks for replying. Even if I enable offline persistence as soon as I update the database and user get online it will sync. I want to save it so it became Independent from the database. I'll upload a picture

Comment: Ah, why do you want something to stay on the device when it's deleted from the database? Seems like simply setting a boolean property to stop showing it wherever you don't want it would be easier.

Comment: The heart button on each cardview in the UI is a favorite button, it suppose to make the cardview accessible from the "SAVED" tab, the last tab in the UI.

Comment: I now agree if it's not in the database, it's useless to store it somewhere. But the situation is: a tab full of cardview, and user want to save a few as favorite so those favorite cardview can be shown in a different Tab.